# Python parse a String value and load into a Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to parse a string value and load into a python dictionary

Input:

```
attributes = "LIFETIME=203421,ID=acr44,SCOPE=[open,basic.operation:read,common.operation:write],USER=b611-410e,CLAIMS_"
```

Expected Output :

```
attributesDictionary = { "LIFETIME" : "203421",
                         "ID" : "acr44",
                         "SCOPE" : "[open,basic.operation:read,common.operation:write]",
                         "USER" : "b611-410e",
                         "CLAIMS_" : None
                         }

attributesDictionary["ID"]
>>> 'acr44'

attributesDictionary["SCOPE"]
>>> '[open,basic.operation:read,common.operation:write]'
```

I am new to python programming. How can we achieve this ?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried using python regex to identify a key value pair separated by '=' . But it is not working for all scenarios

Comment: Could you show the exact code you tried, and an example scenario where it doesn't work?

Comment: If you create the source line, save it to json and then read from json.

Comment: @Evg I am not creating the source line, it is coming as a string value from a gateway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way using `re.split`:

```
import re

d = {}
for k in re.split(",(?![^\[]*\])", attributes):
    key, *val = k.split("=", 1) 
    d[key] = val[0] if val else None
d
```

Output:

```
{'CLAIMS_': None,
 'ID': 'acr44',
 'LIFETIME': '203421',
 'SCOPE': '[open,basic.operation:read,common.operation:write]',
 'USER': 'b611-410e'}
```

Comment: can you please explain me this regex (?![^\[]*\])

Comment: @RaAm. It is looking for `,` to split but not if (i.e. negative lookahead `(?!`) it is inside a part that starts with `[`, and anything (`*`) until `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but here I observed a pattern that all the keys are in capital letter.
If that is the case, You can do the following,

```
import re

attributes = "LIFETIME=203421,ID=acr44,SCOPE=[open,basic.operation:read,common.operation:write],USER=b611-410e,CLAIMS_"

keys = re.findall("[A-Z]+", attributes)
values = re.findall("[^A-Z=]+,", attributes)
attributesDictionary = dict(zip(keys,values))
```

this will give you the following output,

```
{'LIFETIME': '203421',
 'ID': 'acr44',
 'SCOPE': '[open,basic.operation:read,common.operation:write]',
 'USER': 'b611-410e',
 'CLAIMS': '_'}
```